# Last save date in excel worksheet footer

Tags: excel, vba, footer, worksheet

I am using Excel 2007 with a workbook that has many sheets. I need to have the date when the worksheet was last saved - in the footer. I was able to find the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With ws.PageSetup
.LeftFooter = "Last Save Time: &T"
.RightFooter = "Last Save Date: &D"
End With
Next ws

Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

This changes every worksheet. I need it to only change a sheet that has been edited (so each worksheet can have a different date).
Is this even possible? Should I use a cell instead of a footer? Or do I have to create multiple workbooks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Remnant suggested, best approach would be to utilize the `Worksheet_Change` event. That means, you need this VBA code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "Last Change Time: " & Format(VBA.Time, "hh:mm:ss")
        .RightFooter = "Last Change Date: " & Format(VBA.Date, "dd/mm/yy")
    End With
End Sub
```

in every of your worksheets. This event is only raised when you change a cells content, not when you change the selection, so it may be what you want.

Remnant also wrote that this would be a "pain to set up" if you have many worksheets.  I think that depends on what you call "many". For up to 20~40 worksheets, the code from above can be easily copied manually to every sheet in a few minutes.

If you already have a workbook and a lot (say, more that 40) sheets, then it may be a good idea to add the code programmatically. Add a separate module to your workbook, containing this code, and run it once:

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertCode()
    Dim VBProj As Object
    Dim VBComp As Object
    Dim CodeMod As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim LineNum As Long

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set VBComp = VBProj.vbcomponents(sh.Name)
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
        With CodeMod
            .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
            LineNum = LineNum + 1
            .InsertLines LineNum, "Me.Pagesetup.LeftFooter = ""Last Change Time: "" & Format(VBA.Time, ""hh:mm:ss"")"
            .InsertLines LineNum + 1, "Me.Pagesetup.RightFooter = ""Last Change Date: "" & Format(VBA.Date, ""dd/mm/yy"")"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

This will add the "Worksheet_Change" event from above to the code section of every sheet.

Comment: Like it! I have to say I have rarely gone down the route of writing VBA code with VBA code but in this instance it seems like a sensible option. Thanks for posting your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you @Remnant and Doc Brown! I have implemented this code on one sheet for now, and it works perfectly. Sorry for not replying to your questions, I did not know how to log in. My cookies were deleted, as I was unaware they were used by the site to log in.  Thanks for the quick answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it modifies every worksheet is because you are doing a "For Each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets".  Change that to only find the worksheet you want to modify and you will be good to go.

For example, if you don't have a reference to the worksheet you want to modify, keep the For Each loop but instead of modifying each one, do a check on the sheet to see if it is the one you want.  If it is, modify the footer.  Otherwise, ignore it.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe you are missing the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to update the footers each time a sheet is changed. This will mean that individual sheets will have different dates / times dependent upon when they were updated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sh.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "Last Save Time: " & Format(VBA.Time, "hh:mm:ss")
        .RightFooter = "Last Save Date: " & Format(VBA.Date, "dd/mm/yy")
    End With
End Sub
```

The user can then save the workbook as normal.

Does this gie you what you need?

Comment: This one will perhaps work, but one problem here is that Excel will take just a change of the current the selection as a worksheet change.

Comment: @Doc Brown - Agreed. The only other solution I can think of is to use the `Worksheet_Change` event on each sheet. The OP says he has 'many sheets' so would be pain to set up but perhaps most robust solution. Did you have an opinion on best way to go in this instance?

Comment: after thinking a while about it, I came up with a solution using your suggestion (see my answer).